# Unexpected "Subquery returned more than 1 value"

Tags: t-sql, group-by, subquery

Tables have this structure: groupTable > lineGroupJoinTable > linesTable  (name are obfuscated names)
I have the following query which returns this error:

> Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the
>   subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as
>   an expression.

The thing is that I expect that since the subquery is group, I should not get this error. I'm probably missing something.

```
UPDATE dbo.groupTable
SET fieldToUpdate = CASE WHEN fieldToUpdate IS NULL THEN NULL ELSE
(
    SELECT  sumTable.fieldToSum FROM
    dbo.groupTable gt
    INNER JOIN
    (
        SELECT lgjt.groupdId1, lgjt.groupdId2, SUM(lt.fieldToSum) as fieldToSum
        FROM lineGroupJoinTable lgjt
        INNER JOIN linesTable lt
            ON
                lt.fieldToSum IS NOT NULL AND lt.fieldToSum > 0 AND
                lgjt.lineId1 = lt.lineId1 AND lgjt.lineId2 = lt.lineId2
        GROUP BY lgjt.groupdId1, lgjt.groupdId2

    ) sumTable
    ON sumTable.groupdId1 = gt.groupdId1 AND sumTable.groupdId2 = gt.groupdId2
)
END
```

This variation was also try following a suggestion but return the same error:

```
UPDATE dbo.groupTable
SET fieldToUpdate = CASE WHEN fieldToUpdate IS NULL THEN NULL ELSE
(
    SELECT  SUM(sumTable.fieldToSum) FROM
    dbo.groupTable gt
    INNER JOIN
    (
        SELECT lgjt.groupdId1, lgjt.groupdId2, SUM(lt.fieldToSum) as fieldToSum
        FROM lineGroupJoinTable lgjt
        INNER JOIN linesTable lt
            ON
                lt.fieldToSum IS NOT NULL AND lt.fieldToSum > 0 AND
                lgjt.lineId1 = lt.lineId1 AND lgjt.lineId2 = lt.lineId2
        GROUP BY lgjt.groupdId1, lgjt.groupdId2

    ) sumTable
    ON sumTable.groupdId1 = gt.groupdId1 AND sumTable.groupdId2 = gt.groupdId2
    GROUP BY gt.groupdId1, gt.groupdId2
)
END
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably because dbo.groupTable has multiple value for the combination id1 and id2. I suggest to group on the id1 and id2 column and do a SUM, that case you will have only 1 result.

```
UPDATE dbo.groupTable
SET fieldToUpdate = CASE WHEN fieldToUpdate IS NULL THEN NULL ELSE
(
    SELECT  SUM(sumTable.fieldToSum) FROM
    dbo.groupTable gt
    INNER JOIN
    (
        SELECT lgjt.id1, lgjt.id2, SUM(lt.fieldToSum) as fieldToSum
        FROM lineGroupJoinTable lgjt
        INNER JOIN linesTable lt
            ON
                lt.fieldToSum IS NOT NULL AND lt.fieldToSum > 0 AND
                lgjt.id3 = lt.id3 AND lgjt.id4 = lt.id4
        GROUP BY lgjt.id1, lgjt.id2
    ) sumTable
    ON  sumTable.id1 = gt.id1 AND sumTable.id2 = gt.id2
    GROUP BY gt.id1, gt.id2
)
END
```

Comment: I tried this, result is similar. And given the id1 and id2 are a primary key, I don't expect to have multiple lines by id1,id2 pair.